# Import users/customers in Magento 1.9 without overwriting users/customers users passwords

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, import, importexport, dataflow

As per title, I'm exporting users/customers from a previous Magento installation via the `Dataflow` functionality.

I've a problem with the import: the new installation already has some users/customers, and some of them are also in the exported data from the previous installation. Net result: such users get their password overwritten by the one in the export.

I already tried to blank the password in the exported data but the result is that the customer is unable to login with any password.

How can I handle this?